# how to stop media player in android

Tags: android

when open my apps gallery is running and set current gallery image to imageview and playing one audio file through media player if i come out of my aps even it is running

i tried to give mp.stop() and mp.release() in destroy method but it wont work for me
please suggest me

Thanks in Advance

aSwan

Comment: Are you sure onDestroy() is invoked? Add it to onPause() as well.
mp.stop and mp.release should work. Any exceptions?

Comment: yes onDestroy is working.no exception.even media player is running

Comment: Post some piece of code to help us help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### i have updated my answer! to avoid the "-1´s" =P

```
   if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();  // Stop play
        mp.release(); 
        mp = null; // set Media Player to null
   }
```